# What are the thermal properties of a "perfectly rigid" container?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

can a "perfectly rigid" container be a diathermal boundary? I checked the wikipedia article for heat and read:

> Kinetic theory explains transfers of energy as heat as macroscopic manifestations of the motions and interactions of microscopic constituents such as molecules and photons.

If the microscopic constituents of the container can't move (I assume this is what rigid means) is the only avenue for heat transfer across a rigid container the emission of photons?

Comment: The whole point of the container picture is to keep the system on the inside contained. This means that whatever is inside is free within the boundaries of the container but can't interact with the outside. A perfectly rigid container in a kinetic/statistical picture would not allow for heat exchange, but then, in thermodynamics everything is highly idealized, to begin with, so the "container" is merely imagery for thermodynamic boundary conditions. It's not really needed for calculations (total volume is fixed by a variable V) and does not exist as a realizable physical object.